# Facebook API iOS 5.1 sample?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

There is some tutorial or sample of iOS 5.1 integration with Facebook? I've tried the one on Facebook developer site, but I get error on retaining the properties https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/. I'm really fresh on IOS, so if you can help I would be grateful!

Comment: Facebook has provided such a project: [Sample Project with calls out to FB](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely getting an error using retain because when you created your new project Xcode asked you if you would like to use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) and you selected the check box (I think it is selected by default). ARC disallows manual memory management calls such as retain. Upload the line in question and I'll edit this post to show you how to fix it.

Comment: Hummm I see. With ARC I've to use a static library (I don't know exactly what is the difference). I tried to do that through the terminal, but I've not succeed. That was my first time with the terminal, and I've tiped:/Users/fabiosantos/Downloads/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-397c0b6 2/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh.

But i get an error:


-bash: /Users/fabiosantos/Downloads/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-397c0b6: is a directory

Comment: cd to the directory you listed above, and try calling that command on that specific .sh file inside that directory. I'm not as familiar as I should be with the terminal, but I thought you meant you are receiving an error in Xcode, if that's the case I can probably help you with that.